# How to escape the Google Adsense login loop

Tags: blog, google-adsense

I am trying to get Google Adsense for my blog. I complete the form and click "Save and Continue" and it goes back to the homepage. I click "sign in" and it asks for my email and... surprise surprise... goes back to the homepage. I click sign in again and it comes back to the homepage, except with a little balloon that says my email is not associated with a Google Adsense account and gives me the option of signing in with a relevant account or creating a new account. I use the create new account function (on the normal homepage, and the balloon on different times) and it's always the same thing except it doesn't even ask for me to sign in to Gmail anymore. I have tried clearing the cache, and the process just repeats.

All the blog posts I could find on the subject dated back to 2014 at the latest, and as you can imagine were irrelevant. How can I break the login loop?

I am using Google Chrome on Kubuntu 18.04

EDIT: I have tried on multiple computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. I just created a new email address and used a private browsing session.