# Does the Google Adsense underage policy apply if operated by an adult?

Tags: blog, google-adsense, legal

Is it allowed to use Google Adsense underage, if an adult creates and manages the account? Using the adult's email is not an option, it must be the underage one.
The adult's bank account can be used for payments.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. The 2nd section of ToS states:

> 2. Access to the Services; AdSense Accounts
>      Your use of the Services is subject to your creation and our approval of an AdSense Account (an "Account").  We have the right to refuse or limit your access to the Services. In order to verify your Account, from time-to-time we may ask for additional information from you, including, but not limited to, verification of your name, address, and other identifying information. By submitting an application to use the Services, if you are an individual, you represent that you are **at least 18 years of age**.  You may only have one Account. If you (including those under your direction or control) create multiple Accounts, you will not be entitled to further payment from Google, and your Accounts will be subject to termination, pursuant to the provisions below.

If a used email was part of Google Family Link, Google Adsense service may be terminated due to a violation of ToS.

Comment: Ok, how would my parents set this up? They have the problems described here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130868/how-to-escape-the-google-adsense-login-loop however I don't with my partially-created account.

Comment: do you have regular google account or family link account under the supervision of your parents?

Comment: I don't think I do, my parents don't really understand the concept.

Comment: in that case, just apply for Adsense and see what happens